# On the continuity of the mapping $f \mapsto f'$ in the topology of compact convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I want to show that the mapping $f \mapsto f'$ on $\mathcal{H}(U)$ for some domain $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is continuous in the topology of compact convergence equipped with the metric
$$d(f,g) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{|f-g|_{K_n}}{1-|f-g|_{K_n}}$$
where $K_n$ is a compact exhaustion of $U$ and $|f-g|_{K_n}$ denotes the sup norm on $K_n$.

Therefore I need to show that for all $\delta>0$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ sucht that whenever $d(f,g) < \epsilon$ I have that $d(f',g') < \delta$. Now I don't have an idea how to estimate $d(f',g')$ by $d(f,g)$. I tried to use the definition that $f$ is complex differentiable at $a\in U$ if there is a function $f'(x)$ such that $$f(x) = f(a) + f'(x)(x-a)$$ but it led me nowhere. I also tried to use the difference quotient $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
and insert it into the definition of $d(f',g')$. Do you have any hints?

Comment: @GEdgar I want to show that it is continuous. I guess there is no counterexample if I am supposed to show that it is true :)

Comment: OK, $\mathcal H$ means holomorphic?  And not $U \in \mathbb C$ but actually $U \subseteq \mathbb C$ ?  This fails in the real case, so you have to use some theorem about holomorphic functions not available for real-analytic functions.

Comment: Yup it means holomorphic. The other sign is a typo, I'll fix it.

Comment: My hint is ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out